# How do I substitute a recipe that calls for yellow cornmeal for self rising corn meal mix

Tags: baking, substitutions

I have a recipe that I am trying to make but it calls for regular yellow cornmeal. I have self rising yellow corn meal mix, so the question is how do I make the recipe turn out right? It calls for

- 3 cups all purpose flour
- 1 cup yellow corn meal
- 1/4 cup of sugar
- 2 Tbsp baking powder
- 2 tsp of salt
- 2 cups of milk
- 3 extra large eggs
- 2 sticks of butter

It also calls for jalapenos, cheddar, and scallions.

Comment: Hi Jessica, I'm sorry but this site really isn't able to provide just in time answers. We need time to allow our users to see the questions and respond. Also, you haven't really given us enough information. What's *in* the cornmeal mix? Some may have only a leavener and others may have flour and sugar and baking powder... we need to know what it contains before we can tell you how to substitute for it.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're just making a cornbread (more of a sodabread with cornmeal in it) that has some "fun" things added to it. If that's the case, find whatever cornbread recipe is on the side of your self-rising cornmeal-and-flour container and add cheddar, jalapeno, and scallions.

Since we do not know the proportions that constitute the mixture, we have to guess. [This recipe](https://www.bettycrocker.com/recipes/cornbread/8990e15c-fc1d-4a8d-b8b3-4b37f45eca49) suggests that a traditional cornbread is approximately a 1:1:1 ratio (1c corn meal, 1c flour, 1 tbsp baking powder). I'll assume these are the proportions of your mixture.

I would take *2 cups (and a tablespoon)* of self-rising cornmeal mixture, then add 2 cups of flour, and 1 tbsp of baking powder: in total that would make 1 cup of corn meal, 3 cups of flour, and 2 tablespoons of leavening cornmeal. The rest can be figured from there.

Then never buy self-rising anything again! It's much easier and more versatile to just stock baking soda and baking powder as pantry essentials.